# Passing a parameter to GRASS_BATCH_JOB shell script?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.6

This sort of builds off of [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331386/grass-command-line-r-thin-produces-no-output) about GRASS but it is a different issue.

I have a Python script which should kick off a GRASS batch job in a docker container like so:

```
grass_batch_job = f"""
        docker run -v {GRASS_DIR}:/data mundialis/grass-gis-stable /bin/bash -c '
        rm -r /data/{uuid}_mapset;
        grass76 -c epsg:3036 -e /data/{uuid}_mapset;
        export GRASS_BATCH_JOB="/data/script/vectorize_output.sh {uuid}";
        grass76 /data/{uuid}_mapset/PERMANENT;
        unset GRASS_BATCH_JOB'
    """
```

You can see that I have some `{uuid}` references floating about, this is to keep data separated that may be due to multiple processes running in parallel. This seems to be where the problem comes in:

I need to be able to pass this uuid variable to the shell script which i have exported as `GRASS_BATCH_JOB`, so that it knows which image to select to operate on, as per the shell script itself:

```
r.external -o input=/data/$1_paths.tif output=dummy_img
g.region -ap raster=dummy_img
r.reclass input=dummy_img output=dummy_img_nulled rules=/data/script/reclass_rules.txt
r.thin input=dummy_img_nulled output=thinned
r.to.vect thinned output=vectorized type=line
v.out.ogr input=vectorized output=/data/out/out_lines2.shp format=ESRI_Shapefile --overwrite
```

But when I try to do this, I get an error complaining that it can't find the shell script:

```
ERROR: Job file </data/script/vectorize_output.sh fake_UUID> has been defined in the 'GRASS_BATCH_JOB' variable but not found. Exiting.
```

(`fake_UUID` is just a debug UUID value)

Is there a way to get GRASS to recognize that I want to pass a variable to this batch job before running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way that the seems to work. You need to export the UUID variable on the same command line as starting grass. Then within the batch job script the variable $UUID is available in the enviroment,

```
micha@TP480:tmp$ cat << EOF > test_args.sh
> echo "$UUID"
> g.region -p
> EOF
micha@TP480:tmp$ chmod u+x test_args.sh 
micha@TP480:tmp$ export GRASS_BATCH_JOB="./test_args.sh" 
micha@TP480:tmp$ export UUID="Hello"; grass
Cleaning up temporary files...
Starting GRASS GIS...
Executing <./test_args.sh> ...
Hello
projection: 99 (Israel 1993 / Israeli TM Grid)
zone:       0
datum:      towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0
ellipsoid:  grs80
north:      552860.19929577
south:      552241.02033451
west:       219814.56338028
east:       220395.65457746
nsres:      1.00028911
ewres:      1.00015697
rows:       619
cols:       581
cells:      359639
Execution of <./test_args.sh> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
micha@TP480:tmp$ unset GRASS_BATCH_JOB
```

As you see, the variable $UUID can be referenced from within the script when it was exported before starting grass. Somewhat clunky, but it might help.